# How to remove --disable-web-security warning chrome message

Tags: google-chrome

I need to use chrome with --disable-web-security parameter,  it works , but i can't remove the warning message that appears at launch, i have tried also with the --allow-running-insecure-content but without success.

Comment: Why are you using that flag at all when it's dangerous and there are [simple and safe alternatives](https://games.greggman.com/game/dont-disable-web-security/)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to dismiss the message by clicking the "X" icon on the right.

[image: --disable-web-security parameter with "X" icon"]

However, a warning will always appear at startup, because it is dangerous and we need to display this to the user/developer. (Else, a piece of software could easily modify your default Chrome launch flags, and you would never notice you are unsafe.)
There might be a more targeted flag for this purpose in the future, but it would probably still have this warning: https://crbug.com/441605